# Cygwin: Handle python scripts as Window programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, cygwin

In my setup on Windows I use Cygwin because I like Bash, but I use Windows' Python to make sure everything is compatible with the version my colleagues use.

Typically, when I execute a windows program on Cygwin, it will just let Windows open the program. E.g.

`code some_file.txt`

just opens VS Code, an installed Windows program.

Recently I configured windows to run python scripts directly. Now if I open Windows command prompt and I write

`my_script.py argA argB`

it works as expected.

When I do this in Cygwin I get errors of the type

`line 1: import: command not found`

If I add a shebang (e.g. `#!python`) to the script I get

`/cygdrive/c/Users/.../my_script.py [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

and I understand why.

My question then is:
Is there any way I can tell Cygwin to just let Windows handle my Python scripts like it does with other Windows programs?

Alternatively: Is there any way I can make use `cygpath -w` (in the shebang?) to have it pass the Windows-style path to the interpreter but without having to explicitly write it every time?

Comment: have you tried `cygstart my_script.py argA argB` ?

Comment: I did not know about `cygstart`, thanks for the tip! I gave a quick try and it seems to be opening a separate CMD window... do you know if there any way to have `cygstart` redirect the output of the opened program to the current shell?

Comment: cygstart detachs the program. To remain in the same terminal try `cmd /c my_script.py argA argB` . You may need `CYGWIN=disable_pcon` before starting Cygwin if you have strange terminal output. https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html